# Установить openCV 4.0.1 в docker

Tags: linux, docker

Нужно установить openCV версии 4.0.1 в докер, примеры из гугла используют версии ниже 4 и, к сожалению, по аналогии установить не получается.
Dockerfile:

```
# start with ubuntu

FROM ubuntu
ENV TZ=Europe/Moscow
RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/$TZ /etc/localtime && echo $TZ > 
    /etc/timezone

RUN apt-get update -y ; \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common

# install Java 8
RUN echo oracle-java8-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select 
    true | debconf-set-selections && \
    add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y oracle-java8-installer && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/oracle-jdk8-installer

# add java to path
ENV JAVA_HOME /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
ENV PATH $PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin

# install dependencies etc
RUN apt-get update -y ; \
    apt-get install -y build-essential checkinstall cmake pkg-config yasm \
    opencv-data libopencv-dev \
    ant default-jdk \
    ant git unzip curl

WORKDIR /home

RUN git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv.git \
    git clone https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib.git \
    mkdir build && cd build \
    cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
    -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local \
    -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
    -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=~/opencv_build/opencv_contrib/modules \
    -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON .. \

ADD /target/tin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar tin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","tin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему с помощью

```
 # cd to /tmp and clone repos for OpenCV and extra modules
 WORKDIR /tmp
 RUN git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv.git
 RUN git clone https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib.git

 # Create build folder
 WORKDIR /tmp/opencv
 RUN mkdir /tmp/opencv/build
 WORKDIR /tmp/opencv/build

 # Build OpenCV
 RUN cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D 
 BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON -D WITH_V4L=ON -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON -D 
 OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=/tmp/opencv_contrib/modules ..
 RUN make
 RUN make install
 RUN echo "/usr/local/lib" > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf
 RUN ldconfig
```